# Heroku / Rails3: Heroku db:pull --> Internal Server Error. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I'm not particularly adept at describing the application deployment process.  (I am more of a coder than a sysadmin).  However, I really need to backup to my local machine my database from my Heroku deployment before pushing my new code out to Heroku and running a db migration.  So, I'm trying to run heroku db:pull.  When I do, I get the following Internal Server Error:

C:\Users\Morris\railsdev[[application]]>heroku db:pull

```
Loaded Taps v0.3.14
Auto-detected local database: sqlite://db/development.sqlite3
Warning: Data in the database 'sqlite://db/development.sqlite3' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)? y
 !   Internal server error
```

So, I examined the log to get the backtrace.  Here's what I get:

```
==> cron-4139529.log (crash) 
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:330:in `pull'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:22:in `parse'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/document.rb:227:in `build'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/document.rb:43:in `initialize'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8
/gems/xml-simple-1.0.12/lib/xmlsimple.rb:959:in `new'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8
/gems/xml-simple-1.0.12/lib/xmlsimple.rb:959:in `parse'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8
/gems/xml-simple-1.0.12/lib/xmlsimple.rb:164:in `xml_in'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8
/gems/xml-simple-1.0.12/lib/xmlsimple.rb:203:in `xml_in'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8
/bundler/gems/tumblr-oauth-baa3f24a267c/lib/tumblr/request.rb:52:in `authenticat
e'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8
/bundler/gems/tumblr-oauth-baa3f24a267c/lib/tumblr/user.rb:10:in `initialize'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/app/models/tumblog.rb
:181:in `new'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/app/models/tumblog.rb
:181:in `update_followers'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/app/models/tumblog.rb
:178:in `each'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/app/models/tumblog.rb
:178:in `update_followers'
/disk1/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/Rakefile:11
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/home/slugs/804b0fd8-de4e-44aa-9961-75f718fcf3d8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19
...
Missing end tag for 'link' (got "head")
Line:
Position:
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
      Your application crashed.

       Examine the backtrace above this message to debug.
```

I should note that the application runs fine on the server (and locally) as accessed through the web browser.  Does anyone know why I am unable to pull my database?

Comment: I've now answered this with the help of Heroku.  Sometimes you can't blame yourself.  The problem was on their end.

Answer (score 2):

db:pull is really slow with large datasets. Just for future reference, you might want to look at their [pgbackups](http://docs.heroku.com/pgbackups) to capture a dump from the Postgres database rather than transferring record by record like db:pull:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture
```